# Read a CSV and get the summation of a column based on a condition

Tags: c#, csv

I'm learning about .csv file handling in C#.

Suppose I have a .csv file that contains the following data.

```
industryName,value,currency 

Engineering,1000,USD

Agriculture,2000,EUR

Engineering,3000,LKR

Agriculture,4000,USD
```

I want to get the summation of the column named `value` **if the currency is USD only**.
For example, summation in this dataset will be `5000`(1000+4000)

It is highly appreciated if someone can give a code snippet with the answer.

Comment: Nobody can give it to you. You can try it on your own, and then someone can help you once you get stuck.

Comment: You may look at NuGet package [CSVHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) or you can just read it as text using [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 2):

Read the data into simple objects

```
public class IndustryValue
{
    public string IndustryName { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<IndustryValue> GetIndustryValues(/* whatever parmas you need to get the csv data*/)
{
    List<IndustryValue> industries = //get you industries from csv

    return industries;
}
```

Then use simple linq to the sum

```
var byIndustry = industryValues.Where(i => i.Industry.Equals("Agriculture")).Sum(i => i.Value);

var byCurrency = industryValues.Where(i => i.Currency.Equals("USD")).Sum(i => i.Value);

var byIndustryAndCurrency = industryValues.Where(i => i.Industry.Equals("Agriculture") && i.Currency.Equals("USD")).Sum(i => i.Value);
```